# How to use javascript variable to change the height of the div using cssText

Tags: javascript, css

```
var randomHeight = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+50);
document.getElementById("child").style.cssText="background-color:red; height:randomHeight+'px'; width:100px;";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need string concatenation or [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Also element should be `display:block;`

> Concatenation

```js
var randomHeight = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+50);
document.getElementById("child").style.cssText="display:block;background-color:red; height:"+randomHeight+"px; width:100px;";
```

```html
<span id="child">ABC</span>
```

> Template literals

```js
var randomHeight = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+50);
document.getElementById("child1").style.cssText=`display:block;background-color:red; height:${randomHeight}px; width:100px;`;
```

```html
<span id="child1">Def</span>
```